# Need help understanding a programming challenge

Tags: algorithm, data-structures

I have already checked others solutions but i am unable to figure out, how they are solving this problem.
https://www.hackerrank.com/challenges/castle-on-the-grid

And if anyone can help suggest where i should study from to begin to comprehend such problems,that would be great.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you link to is a classic shortest-path problem anf those are typically solved with breadth-first algorithms.

You should read up on [Dijkstras bfs](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dijkstra%27s_algorithm) and [A*](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/A*_search_algorithm).